# Higgs-fermions coupling in CalcHEP?

Tags: particle-physics, computational-physics, feynman-diagrams, higgs, software

I started using [CalcHEP](http://theory.sinp.msu.ru/~pukhov/calchep.html) for some analytical calculations, and in looking at Higgs decays, I noticed that the default model file (as well as some other files available online) mention Higgs coupling to fermion pairs for the muon-antimuon and the tau-antitau (so hmM and hlL couplings according to the CalcHEP syntax), but not with the electron-positron (no heE term). Is that by design (kinematics as the electron is too light)?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it deals with details of software files and associated choice of the original programmers rather than physics.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero: It seems to me that the design choice is tied to physics, so it should stay open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that the default Lagrangian contains only [five Yukawa interactions](https://github.com/restrepo/CalcHEP/blob/master/models/lgrng1.mdl#L18#L22) for the [muon](https://github.com/restrepo/CalcHEP/blob/master/models/prtcls1.mdl#L11), [tau](https://github.com/restrepo/CalcHEP/blob/master/models/prtcls1.mdl#L13) and [three heavy quarks](https://github.com/restrepo/CalcHEP/blob/master/models/prtcls1.mdl#L18#L20). This is an approximation in which the [electron](https://github.com/restrepo/CalcHEP/blob/master/models/prtcls1.mdl#L9) and [light quarks](https://github.com/restrepo/CalcHEP/blob/master/models/prtcls1.mdl#L15#L17) are massless and hence have no Yukawa interactions because $y \propto m$.

Comment: This is weird, as I thought that this would be more of a kinematic approximation, to be performed at the level of the symbolic $|\mathcal{M}|^2$ level, while the input parameters would be kept regardless of how small they really are.

Comment: Dynamics usually refers to the $|M|^2$ factor. The Lorentz invariance phase space factor $d\Phi$ is usually referred to as kinematic.

Comment: I must have mixed up my terminology, thanks. I meant that I thought that any  approximation (for example, the relativistic limit, where masses vanish) are applied at the "dynamics" level, as in _after_ the calculation for $|\mathcal{M}|^2$ is performed.

Comment: Oh I see. Computationally it makes sense to do it before calculating $|M|^2$ as you can avoid calculating diagrams that ultimately contribute nothing.